# как корректно высчитывать время в python3?

Tags: python-3.x, дата, datetime

Возможно, конечно, я слепой и не нашёл это в документации и на форумах, но как высчитывать время?
Типо мне нужно чтобы выводилось нынешняя дата (date-month-year) и дата, которая была 7 дней назад
Мой прототип был примерно таким:

```
    import datetime
    
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    
    dateNow = str(now.day) + '-' + str(now.month) + '-' + str(now.year)
    dateAgo = str(now.day - 7) + '-' + str(now.month) + '-' + str(now.year)
    print(dateNow)
    print(dateAgo)
```

Но он не увенчался успехом, т.к. в начале месяца дата просто будет становиться отрицательным числом .-.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/441152/4804629

Comment: Для форматирования даты есть специальные функции, например, strftime(). И не придётся придумывать свои костыли.

Comment: @Эникейщик автору не форматировать , а менять дату надо на заданный временной интервал

Comment: @splash58 поэтому я и написал комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: @Эникейщик, ну, как раз таки этот костыль я написал потому, что нужно менять дату на 7 дней назад, а с strftime(), насколько я понял, нельзя её изменять

Comment: Под костылем я имел в виду ваш способ формирования строки для вывода, а не изменение даты.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

n = datetime.now()
print(n, '\n')
# Если нам нуж единицы времени такие как неделя и меньше то вполне достаточно timedelta
print(n - timedelta(weeks=5, hours=3, minutes=25, seconds=12))

# Если нам нужны такие единицы как месяц и год, то нам понадобится билиотека python-dateutil
# pip install python-dateutil (Если не установлена)

print(n - relativedelta(years=2, months=3, days=11, hours=2, minutes=10, seconds=51))

#2021-12-18 05:50:16.126490 

#2021-11-13 02:25:04.126490
#2019-09-07 03:39:25.126490
```

> В relevantdelta так-же можно задасать недели